# 500 error when trying to parse this php script, for adding information to my MYSQL database from a html form

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my code.
I keep getting a 500 internal server error when trying to parse it, its loaded after the form is completed and the button is pressed all information is sent to it by POST, I have no idea whats causing this.
I'm kinda newish to php.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'reboot');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');



$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

$value = $_POST['user_uploaded_files'];
$value = $_POST['Developer?'];
$value = $_POST['size'];
$value = $_POST['Email'];
$value = $_POST['url'];
$value = $_POST['title']

{  mysql_query($sql)  = "INSERT INTO links (user_uploaded_files,                  
developer_status, size, Email 
url,title) VALUES ('$value', '$value2',
'$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";

mysql_close();}

?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You have a number of syntax errors you need to correct. You have curly brackets where you don't need them, you're overwriting `$value` several times. There are other problems. You may want to go take a basic online PHP course before you go any further.

Comment: You should start debugging with error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @chris85 That function won't work if there's a syntax error, since nothing in the script runs. He needs to check the PHP error log.

Answer (score 1):

The line with `'Developer?'` I hope that input has `name="Developer?"` as an attribute.

As well, you've set the variable `$value` a few times. That gets overwritten every time you set it. So `$value` ends up being set to `$_POST['title']` which I'm sure isn't what you wanted. Looks like your SQL query is looking for `$value`, `$value2`, etc. But those don't exist yet.

After `$_POST['title']`, you're missing a semicolon.

Moving on, the next line starts with just a `{`. The curly braces are used for control structures, you cant just wrap code in them.

What you most likely wanted was

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO...";

if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) { ...
```

Check out the [docs on mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to see how to correctly use it.

However, **you shouldn't even be using the old mysql_* functions, they're old and shouldn't be used anymore.**

When you get a 500 error, something is usually written to a log file somewhere. You should find it and check it often when this happens.

You  may want to go looking for some beginner PHP tutorials to familiarize yourself with the general syntax and how basic things work.

Comment: Way more than a missing semi-colon and unnecessary curly brackets.

Comment: Yeah I just glanced at it to start, I tried to point out everything I saw in the question through numerous edits. May not have been enough though :/